# Create a subclass from an instance to override a few methods?

Tags: java, inheritance

For testing purposes, I want to replace the implementation of a few methods of an object that implements some interface. One way of doing this would be to create a new object, passing the instance as a parameter to the constructor, and manually recreating all of the methods to use the instance's methods for all but a couple of methods, which would be overridden for testing purposes. Unfortunately, the interface has a large number of methods, which makes this option tedious.

Is there some way to create an object that is a "subclass of an instance of an object" in the sense that it simply calls the instance's method's for all calls except when overridden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dynamic Proxy Classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) may be a way to go. I have never used it before, however it is a viable mechanism to catch every method invocation and decide whether to invoke old method or do something else and/or extra.

The link I provided has even an example of `DebugProxy` which may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 4):

Create a mock using some mocking framework like [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/):

```
MyComplexInterface mock = Mockito.mock(MyComplexInterface.class);
Mockito.when(mock.someMethod()).thenReturn("some value");
```

Mockito are able to mock both interfaces and concrete classes.

Comment: This kind of testing is EXACTLY what mocking frameworks were made for.

Answer (score 1):

> For testing purposes, I want to
>   replace the implementation of a few
>   methods of an object that implements
>   some interface.

Simply create a class that extends the current concrete class, and override only those methods from the interface you want to test.

```
public class ForTest extends X {

    @Override
    public void m1() { 
        .
        .
        .
    }

}

public class X implements Z{ 

//all the overrides

}

interface Z { 

//lots of methods

}
```

Comment: I need the data from the instance though. There's a large number of fields.

Comment: So construct the ForTest instances wherever you currently construct the original instances with the populated data.

Comment: The point is I'm trying to avoid explicitly implementing all of the methods and explicitly copying all of the fields.

Comment: but u dont have to. when u subclass, u will get all the members and methods for free.

Comment: Not copies of them, though. There are a lot of members that have been loaded with lots of data. At a certain point in testing, I want a few methods to have some different behavior (these are some lookup methods, and I want to provide some dummy lookup values).

Comment: I can see @jonderry's point.  He needs a wrapper class, but he doesn't want the overhead of creating all of the methods ... most of which simply delegate to the wrapped object.